# Query Cache Implementation Details

Tags: mysql, caching, query-cache

kindly help me in finding a low level documentation for Query Cache module in MySQL since I am planning to work with the source code of Query Cache. I googled a lot but I was provided with only high level details. Is it available in MySQL website (I tried but not an exhaustive search)? Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

The best thing and probably the only low level documentation is the source code itself. It explains the architecture moderately well!

Files are: sql_cache.cc and sql_cache.h